# Difference between freezing layer with requires_grad and not passing params to optim in PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Let's say I train an autoencoder.
I want to freeze the parameters of the encoder for the training, so only the decoder trains.

I can do this using:

```
# assuming it's a single layer called 'encoder'
model.encoder.weights.data.requers_grad = False
```

Or I can pass only the decoder's parameters to the optimizer. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most practical way is to iterate through all parameters of the module you want to freeze and set `required_grad` to `False`. This gives you the flexibility to switch your modules on and off without having to initialize a new optimizer each time. You can do this using the [`parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=parameters#torch.nn.Module.parameters) generator available on all [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html)s:

```
for param in module.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

This method is model agnostic since you don't have to worry whether your module contains multiple layers or sub-modules.

---

Alternatively, you can call the function `nn.Module.requires_grad_` once as:

```
module.requires_grad_(False)
```

Comment: model.parameters() shows me all parameters in the network, I want a single layer of sub-model

Comment: Indeed, but I wrote `module.parameters()`, *i.e.* you can replace `module` with `model.encoder` in your case.